# One single apache process for Wordpress consuming 100% CPU. What to do?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I'm running a Wordpress website on a micro instance at Amazon. For those trying to figured it out how to do it, there is plenty of tutorials on the web (to start). After starting, the problems come in. First I had to install MySQL 5.6, since the version installed on the machine didn't work out. Then I've successfully handled the memory issues turning "performance_schema = 0" on the section [mysqld] of "/etc/my.cnf". I also limited Apache prefork specs on "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" to:

- StartServers       6
- MinSpareServers    6
- MaxSpareServers   6
- MaxClients       6
- MaxRequestsPerChild  1000

After a couple of hours with the website live and running, it went down and I found out that all the 6 apache processes were consunming all the CPU (about 16% of CPU each, as seen on $ top). "Maybe I can't have these much processes running at the same time" I thought. I changed the number 6 above for 1, and the same problem: the single process alone is consuming all the CPU.

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

- 2773 apache    20   0  430m 107m  13m R 99.0 10.8   2:41.35 httpd

I don't have anything more running on the machine besides the Wordpress site with a paid theme called "betheme", all its plugins and also Jetpack plugin. It's noteworthy that this website is a pretty simple single page. No blog, no comments.

What should I do? Anyone have experienced this and know the problem?

P.S.: this is my first question here :)

Comment: Check logs. Perhaps google and others crawl you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Putnik

Answer (score 0):

Following @Putnik hint, I checked the Apache log at "/var/log/httpd/access_log". I stumbled across multiple IPs trying to connect to the file "/xmlrpc.php" at every second. I googled the queries and I found out that putting the following lines

```
<Files "xmlrpc.php">
Order Allow,Deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

on the file "/var/www/html/.htaccess" would block the access to "/xmlrpc.php". This has some implications that can be found on the web, such as impossibility to connect to WordPress via some dedicated apps. As my website is pretty simple and I don't need any of those things, VOILÀ, problem solved. Now my Apache processes don't burn the CPU.

Comment: Hackers. Fail2ban is another option to deal with them.